# sklearn: semi-supervised learning - LabelSpreadingModel memory error

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using the `sklearn LabelSpreadingModel` as below:

```
label_spreading_model = LabelSpreading()
model_s = label_spreading_model.fit(my_inputs, labels)
```

But I got the following errors:

```
   MemoryErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-17-73adbf1fc908> in <module>()
         11 
         12 label_spreading_model = LabelSpreading()
    ---> 13 model_s = label_spreading_model.fit(my_inputs, labels)

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/semi_supervised/label_propagation.pyc in fit(self, X, y)
        224 
        225         # actual graph construction (implementations should override this)
    --> 226         graph_matrix = self._build_graph()
        227 
        228         # label construction

    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/semi_supervised/label_propagation.pyc in _build_graph(self)
        455         affinity_matrix = self._get_kernel(self.X_)
        456         laplacian = graph_laplacian(affinity_matrix, normed=True)
    --> 457         laplacian = -laplacian
        458         if sparse.isspmatrix(laplacian):
        459             diag_mask = (laplacian.row == laplacian.col)

    MemoryError:
```

Looks like something wrong with the laplacian of my input matrix. Is there any parameter I can config or any change that I can avoid this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

**It's obvious: your PC is running out of memory.**

As you are not setting any parameters, the **rbf-kernel is used by default** ([proof](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelSpreading.html#sklearn.semi_supervised.LabelSpreading)).

Some excerpt from [scikit-learn's docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/label_propagation.html#label-propagation):

```
The RBF kernel will produce a fully connected graph which is represented in
memory by a dense matrix. This matrix may be very large and combined with the 
cost of performing a full matrix multiplication calculation for each iteration
of the algorithm can lead to prohibitively long running times
```

Maybe the following (next sentence in the docs above) will help:

```
On the other hand, the KNN kernel will produce a much more memory-friendly 
sparse matrix which can drastically reduce running times.
```

But i don't know your data, PC-configuration and co. and can only guess...